# How to call a a REST API method with a dash "-" in the method name?

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, http-status-code-405

I am trying to communicate with a REST API using cURL and PHP. The problem is that one of the methods that I want to call has a dash "-" in its name.

Every time I call this method I get this error `HTTP Code: 405 Specified method is not allowed for this resource.`

This is the URI that I am posting data to is `/directories/lookup-entries`

What can I do to properly `POST` data to this API

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the API. Is this API developed by you? Or someone else? What does the API specs say the URI should be?

Comment: The API is developed by interaction intelligence to interact with a telephony system. The irk should be like this http://domain:port/ices/{sessionID}//directories/lookup-entries

Comment: `405` means that the HTTP method you use is not accepted by this resource. Which method do you use? `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, ...?

Comment: I use POST as per the API documentation

Comment: If you have done it according to specification, and all other endpoints work, it is probably a bug with that API, and nothing to do with dashes - dashes are perfectly fine in URI / URLs. You may wish to file a report with the API vendor.

Comment: Light, your right it was an issue in the API from the vendor. If you post your comment in an answer I will accept it. Thank you :)